# Comperator caused "Comparison method violates its general contract!" - 1300 items sort

Tags: sorting, java-7

I have data of 1300 items, sorted with my comperator. Sorting is working fine when I'm using JAVA 6. 
When project is run on JAVA 7 I'm getting this exception:

env: JAVA 7, Vaadin 6.8.12, tested with both 32 bit and 64 bit same error occured. ( It is working fine on JAVA 6 )

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(TimSort.java:747)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:483)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:410)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:214)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:217)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.AbstractInMemoryContainer.doSort(AbstractInMemoryContainer.java:575)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.AbstractInMemoryContainer.sortContainer(AbstractInMemoryContainer.java:555)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.AbstractBeanContainer.sort(AbstractBeanContainer.java:440)
    at com.vaadin.ui.CustomTable.sort(CustomTable.java:4552)
```

This is comperator which I'm using:

```
private class StudyRecordComparator implements Comparator<Object> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        if (o1 instanceof String && o2 instanceof String) {
            return ((String) o1).compareToIgnoreCase(((String) o2));
        }
        else if (o1 instanceof QuestionnaireStatusType && o2 instanceof QuestionnaireStatusType) {
            QuestionnaireStatusType status1 = (QuestionnaireStatusType) o1;
            QuestionnaireStatusType status2 = (QuestionnaireStatusType) o2;
            if(status1.equals(status2)) {
                return 0;
            }
            switch(status1) {
                case WAITING_FOR_REVIEW :
                    return -1;

                case IN_REVIEW :
                    if(status2.equals(QuestionnaireStatusType.WAITING_FOR_REVIEW)) {
                        return 1;
                    } else {
                        return -1;
                    }
                case WAITING_PUBLICATION :
                    if(status2.equals(QuestionnaireStatusType.WAITING_FOR_REVIEW) || status2.equals(QuestionnaireStatusType.IN_REVIEW)) {
                        return 1;
                    } else {
                        return -1;
                    }
                case PUBLISHED :
                    if(status2.equals(QuestionnaireStatusType.WITHDRAWN)) {
                        return -1;
                    } else {
                        return 11;
                    }
                case WITHDRAWN :
                    return 1;

            }
        }
        else if (o1 instanceof Date && o2 instanceof Date) {
            return ((Date) o1).compareTo(((Date) o2));
        } else if (o1 instanceof Integer && o2 instanceof Integer) {
            return ((Integer) o1).compareTo(((Integer) o2));
        } else if (o1 instanceof User && o2 instanceof User) {
            return ((User)o1).toString().compareToIgnoreCase(((User)o2).toString());
        }

        return 0;
    }

}
```

---

```
public enum QuestionnaireStatusType {

IN_PROGRESS("In progress"), 
WAITING_FOR_REVIEW("Waiting for review"),
IN_REVIEW("In review"),
WAITING_PUBLICATION("Waiting for publication"),
PUBLISHED("Published"),
WITHDRAWN("Withdrawn");

private final String field;

public String getField() {
    return field;
}

QuestionnaireStatusType(String field){
    this.field = field;
}
```

}

Comment: If you cannot fix this, you can disable this check by setting `System.setProperty("java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort", "true");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Comparison%20method%20violates%20its%20general%20contract%22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your collection contain `null`?

If so, there is one problem with your comparator: It always returns 0 for `null`, so `null` is considered equal to everything.

As a result for `A > B` (premise), you will also have `A == null` and `null == B` so by transitivity `A` and `B` should also be equal, which violates the premise.

You need to establish a total and consistent ordering for all possible values (including `null` if that is allowed).

The same issue occurs when your collection contains mixed types (some Strings, some Dates, some QuestionnaireStatusType).